# How does this count-even racket function work?

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I am trying to understand how the count-even function given in my textbook works and I'm not sure if I completely understand it.

I have provided my understanding of the function in comments next to code. Can someone explain what is happening and correct me in each step of this function.

And I don't understand how this function is recursive. What is the base case ?

```
(define (ce x)           ; x is an argument that takes in a list
 (if (pair? x)                    ; I don't understand why this is here
  (+ (ce (car x))        ; Add the resuls of recursive call together (0 or 1)
     (ce (cdr x)))
  (if (and (number? x) (even? x)) ; if x is a number and x is even then return 1 ? Else return 0 ?
      1
      0) ) )
```

Comment: One can appreciate _why_ this `count-evens` is written this way by trying it on a few arguments: try the following for `x`: `'()`, `2`, `'(0 1 2)`, `'(0 1 . 2)`, `'(((0) 1) 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a recursive function there are usually two cases:

1. The result is a call to the same function
2. The result is a simple value, the base case

You choose between the two cases with an `if`.

Hence the base case is:

```
(if (and (number? x) (even? x))
    1
    0) ) )
```

And the recursive case is:

```
  (+ (count-evens (car x))        
     (count-evens (cdr x)))
```

Comments:

1. The argument `x` doesn't need to be a list. `pairs?` tests for a list. If it is just a value then we have the base case. If an even number then result is one, else zero.
2. If the argument `x` is a list, we split it into two parts, the head (`car`) and the tail (`cdr`). The head is just a value, and so when we rerun `count-evens` on it we end up with the base case.
3. The tail is passed to `count-evens` which keeps slicing off a value at a time until we have a value in the `car` and empty list in `cdr`. In the base case,  the first value is assessed for an even number, and the empty list is always evaluated as zero.